# driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies(); not working for Edge Browser Windows 10 selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies

My code:

```
driver = new EdgeDriver("D://Projects//Selenium Jars//LatestSelenium//");
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    //driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
    driver.Navigate().Refresh();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

This is working in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge

Comment: Which observation makes you feel `driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();` is not working?

Comment: *shakes head*  STFW.  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/5751773/

Comment: Hi DebanjanB,  When i comment the line for clearing cookies the edge browser loads the url specified. But when it is uncommented. The browser alone opens and no url is loaded.  And the error says Unknown error. Below is my full code :

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code and let me know

```
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```